# Caching Views in Memory

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to cache entire Views in ASP.NET Core?

One can use `IMemoryCache` to cache data in ASP.NET Core, however I can't see any way of caching the compiled Views so that they are not recompiled every time they are requested.

I initially tried to cache the `ViewResult` Objects returned by the `View()` method in the Controller, however I later found that these objects are not the actual Views.

To clarify, I would like to be able to cache dynamic Views so that their code is not compiled every time they are requested, only once a specified timeout has been exceeded.

Comment: Have you heard of `[OutputCacheAttribut]`(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Please note, that the framework is called ASP.NET Core 1.x and not ASP.NET 5. It has been renamed almost 18 months ago to **AVOID confusion**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by specifying `OutputCache` attribute for Action/Controller.

As [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) stated:

> **OutputCacheAttribute**
>
> - Output caching lets you store the output of an action method in 
>     memory on the Web server. For example, if the action method renders a
>     view, the view page will be cached. This cached page is then available to the application for subsequent requests. Output caching saves your application the time and resources it would take to re-create the result of the action method.
> - In ASP.NET MVC, you can use the OutputCacheAttribute attribute to    mark action methods whose output you want to cache. If you mark
>     a    controller with the OutputCacheAttribute attribute, the output
>     of all    action methods in the controller will be cached.
>
> **Properties:**
>
> **[NoStore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.nostore(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute.NoStore)** : Gets or sets a value that indicates whether to store the cache.
>
> **[Duration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.duration(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute.Duration)** : Gets or sets the cache duration, in seconds.

For more Properties, please refer to [OutputCacheAttribute Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute_properties(v=vs.118).aspx)

Please also have a look at this [Improving Performance with Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs).

---

### Update

For **ASP.NET Core** there is also an Attribute called **`Response Caching`**.

According to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response)

> **Response Caching**:
>
> - Response caching adds cache-related headers to responses. These headers specify how you want client, proxy and middleware to cache responses. Response caching can reduce the number of requests a client or proxy makes to the web server. Response caching can also reduce the amount of work the web server performs to generate the response.

Unlike Output cache, it does not store HTTP response at server, it just adds "Cache-Control" header in the response [(Source)](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/response-caching-in-asp-net-core/).